# Menu API not switching menus?

Tags: menus

I am using the menus API, and I want to switch to a different menu, but it is holding the first one for some reason

Here is my code

in functions.php

```
    add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus',10 );

function register_my_menus() {

    register_nav_menu('main-navigation', 'Main Navigation');

}
```

Here is the code in my theme file (header.php)

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'menu' => 'main-navigation',
        'container_id' => 'navigation',
        'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu'
        );
    wp_nav_menu($args); ?>
```

Comment: *@Mild Fuzz*: Can you post the code from your theme that calls `wp_nav_menu` to output to the web page so we can see what it it doing?

Comment: the whole header.php file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

_Menus are somewhat confusing around there. Try this:

```
$args = array(
        'theme_location' => 'main-navigation',
        'container_id' => 'navigation',
        'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu'
        );
    wp_nav_menu($args);
```

`theme_location` tries to display menu that is attached to this location. `menu` tries to display menu by slug/id (not location of menu, but actual menu that you create in admin area).

So you are mixing up location with menu slug, it gets confused and just serves first menu it can.

See [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) documentation for full description of logic behind it.

Comment: no effect, very odd

Comment: Try it now. Rarst accidentally put a hyphen instead of an underscore for `'theme_location'`.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I hate such typos, they are hell to notice and fix. :(

Comment: fix sorted it. Excellent